# DateTime::createFromFormat and incomplete dates

Tags: php, dataformat

I try to use the `createFromFormat` method for formatting dates. Problem is, when the date is incomplete (missing seconds, minutes or hours)  it results into an error. Is there a way to make this work even for incomplete dates like the one below:

```
$my_sql_date = '2011-01-06 09:39';
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $my_sql_date);
print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors());

Array ( 
       [warning_count] => 0 
       [warnings] => Array ( ) 
       [error_count] => 1 
       [errors] => Array ( [16] => Data missing ) 
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using `createFromFormat()` then the format that you specify must match the format of the date/time string that you're passing in.... otherwise it makes `create from format` a pretty meaningless method name.... the solution is to ensure that the string matches the format, even if that means appending `':00'` to the end of that string

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the DateTime object constructor with your format.

```
$incompleteData = '2011-01-06 09:39';
$date2 = new DateTime($incompleteData);
```

The above will work.

Using `DateTime::createFromFormat`. But with this method your incomplete date will always have to conform to the specified format, so the above method is your best bet.

```
$incompleteData = '2011-01-06 09:39';
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $incompleteData);
```

Comment: However, if date is even further incomplete, it will fail - e.g.: new DateTime('2011-01-06 09');

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using the default `__construct`?

```
$my_sql_date = '2011-01-06 09:39';
$date = new DateTime($my_sql_date);
print_r($date);
```

Will produce

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2011-01-06 09:39:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => US/Pacific
)
```

You may format it afterwards:

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

which will result in

```
2011-01-06 09:39:00
```